# Change email domain OS X Server

Tags: email, smtp, postfix, mac-osx-server

I'm having trouble setting up the mail service correctly on my os x leopard server. In server admin, under Mail>General the domain is set to "mydomain.net.nz", and my host name "servername.mydomain.net.nz", yet whenever an account is created, the email address will be user@servername.mydomain.net.nz instead of just user@mydomain.net.nz.

Am I missing something, or is there somewhere I can change this? I have looked in the /etc/postfix/main.cf file, and mydomain is set to just mydomain.net.nz.

The user accounts can send and receive fine, but only to the accounts @servername.mydomain.net.nz.

Email sent externally to the domain are getting "Relay access denied (state 14)."

Where can I change this?

Comment: should probably be tagged "postfix"

Comment: I've came across another gotcha - I was testing the sending from within the squirrelmail webmail. I was doing this at server.domain.net.nz/webmail and was getting frustrated that emails were coming from user@server.domain.net.nz
Later on I was accessing it through server.local/webmail and then noticed that emails were coming from user@server.local
Apparently squirrelmail gets the server name with PHP, so you have to edit the server settings in /etc/squirrelmail/config/config.php to $domain = "yourdomain.com"; to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in main.cf:
For outbound stuff:

```
myorigin = $mydomain
```

For inbound stuff:

```
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
```

see also: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html